# Is it possible to "lock" and prevent adding new columns in Numbers?

Tags: keyboard, numbers

Is it possible to lock the number of columns in a Numbers sheet so that no new columns are added on the right when tabbing through cells? The problem is when I tab through cells from left to right, Numbers adds a new column to the right if I hit tab while in the last column. I'd like to find a way to prevent new columns when tabbing left to right and have hitting tab take the cursor back to the far left column A.

Comment: Don't use the tab key to navigate, use the arrow keys by themselves or with the appropriate modifier key.

Comment: Arrow keys do work; they don't return to the left. Maybe I'm asking too much :)

Comment: Did you not understand the part where I said... "or with the appropriate modifier key."? Pressing Command-Left Arrow returns it to the first column (which is to the far left).